# jQuery .hover() only partially working

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I'm creating my own WordPress theme and I'm encountering some issues I believe are not WordPress-related, but more jQuery-related.

So, in my script I'm using the .hover() function. When I try it out on the website, not all of them are working and it changes when I do some things(e.g. when I right-click to 'Inspect Element' and the Google Chrome DevTools opens, they are all properly working. When I close it, only two of them work...).

I'm also using the Owl Carousel plugin, so maybe it has something to do with that. I currently have two different carousels and when I hover them a certain text is supposed to show (the css is valid). Only the first carousel item actually shows the text on hovering.

I'm gonna add some code for clarification.

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function slidercalc() {
        $('.slider').each(function(i,obj) {
        // some code
        $(this).hover(function() {
            $(this).find(".slider-text").css('height', 'calc(100% - ' + $(this).find(".slider-title").outerHeight() + 'px)');
        }, function() {
            $(this).find(".slider-text").css('height', '0');
        });
    }
slidercalc();
$(window).resize(slidercalc);
});
```

The `.slider` element represents an item in the Owl Carousel. The **HTML** looks like somehow this.

```
<div class="owl-item active">
<div class="slider">
<a href="/">
    <img srcset="
        /896x504.jpg 896w,
        /640x360.jpg 640w,
        /320x180.jpg 320w
    " sizes="
        (min-width: 640px) 896px,
        (min-width: 320px) 640px,
        320px
    " oncontextmenu="return false;">
    <div class="slider-title">Title of this image</div>
    <div class="slider-text" style="bottom: 88px; height: 0px;">
        <span>vr 29 juni 2018</span>
        <p style="max-height: calc(100% - 54px);">Text supposed to showing up on hovering.</p>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

The inline-style added at `.slider-text` and `.slider-text p`is happening because op the jQuery and I believe this is correct.

Comment: did u get any error in console ? and when u load page, div.slider-text elements are hidden or not.

Comment: No, console gives me no errors. When I load the page, the .slider-text elements are hidden, as they should be.